# LINQ and Dictionary Thread Safety

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, linq

I have a `Dictionary<int, bool>`

I had a `InvalidOperationException collection was modified` error that was handled but baffled me why.

The only code I can think it is, is the below:

```
lock (lockObject)
{
   AllowInputs[InputNumber] = true;
}

if (AllowInputs.Values.All(x => x == true))
{
  //Do stuff
}
```

If one thread is within the lock statement modifying a value and another thread is executing the `All(x => x == true)` will this cause the `"Collection was modified"` errror?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to lock (on the same object) both when you read and when you write. The call to `All` internally iterates over all the items in the dictionary. If the dictionary is modified by another thread the iterator becomes invalid and an exception is thrown.

Try this:

```
lock (lockObject)
{
    if (AllowInputs.Values.All(x => x == true))
    {
      //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll move the end of the lock statement to include the All method call

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to either lock on the object when you read or write or look into [the reader writer pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) that allows you to have one writer and multiple readers:

that is, if you are performing multiple reads on the same object.